# One-Many via NHibernate Loquacious mapping by code or xml

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to implement a one-to-many relationship between a person and car, and have CRUD operations on both person and car. Brief CRUD and relationships:

**Update**

- A `person` has many `cars`
- CRUD operations on  both person and car via person object.
- Deleting a person will delete all s/his cars
- Ability to perform CRUD operation on someone's cars, either via person object or car object.

Is it possible via ORM, in particular NHibernate?

Classes like below:

```
public class PersonSet
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<CarSet> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class CarSet
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonSet Person { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping is shown below:

```
  public class PersonSetMap : ClassMapping<PersonSet>
    {
        public PersonSetMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m=>m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x=>x.Name);
            Set(x => x.Cars, c =>
                {
                    //c.Key(k =>
                    //    {
                    //        k.Column("PersonId");
                    //    });
                     c.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                    c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                   // c.Inverse(true);
                }
                , r =>
                    {
                        r.OneToMany();
                    }
                );
        }
    }

    public class CarSetMap : ClassMapping<CarSet>
    {
        public CarSetMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x => x.Name);
            ManyToOne(x => x.Person, m =>
            {
                m.Column("PersonId");
                m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that if I update one car and try to save it on a person object, it doesn't change.

**Update**

I want to find out **if it is possible, and where my mapping above is wrong**. Any idea on either xml version or Loquacious would also be appreciated.

There should be a `PersonId` foreign key on table `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would solve your problem, but in a ManyToOne mapping the Unique and NotNullable methods should be applied at the column level.

```csharp
ManyToOne(x => x.Person, m =>
{
    m.Column(c =>
    {
        c.Name("PersonId");
        c.NotNullable(true);
    });
    m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
});
```